# let the list cross the div border

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with `overflow: auto;`.
Inside the div there is a listthat cross the border of the div and remain partially hidden.
Here s an image:

[image]

In [jsfiddle.net/GQSFH/1](http://jsfiddle.net/GQSFH/1) I need that all of the list structure will be visible.

I would like to show the whole list. How can I do it?

Comment: @Marwan: you took the words right out of my mouth...

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow:visible` or on your parent element/container set a `height` to adjust according to the selection box height.

Comment: @SirB: the list has 200px height, but I don't want the div to have 200px height.

Comment: @SirB: If I make overflow:visible, the div will exceed the horizontal width limit.

Comment: @Naor can you provide your html as well?

Comment: @SirB: I create jsfiddle but it doesn't has the css: http://jsfiddle.net/GKxUD/1/

Comment: @SirB: I managed to make something clearer. In http://jsfiddle.net/GQSFH/1/ I need that all of the list structure will be visible.

Comment: Wow this is a mess. Why is everything in tables?

Comment: @SirB: I know this is wrong but this is something I got and cannot change (not mine).